# Compatible code for Semigroup Monoid Proposal

Tags: haskell, typeclass, monoids, semigroup

[`Semigroup` is becoming a superclass of `Monoid`](https://prime.haskell.org/wiki/Libraries/Proposals/SemigroupMonoid). I did read the recommendations on that page for writing compatible code, but I neither like to conditionally depend on the `semigroups` package nor to put my `mappend` code in a top-level declaration.

My attempt now is

```
#if MIN_VERSION_base(4,9,0)
import Data.Semigroup
#endif

#if MIN_VERSION_base(4,9,0)
instance Semigroup Foo
#endif

instance Monoid Foo where
    mempty = …
    mappend a b = …
```

The `Semigroup` class seems to have a default `<> = mappend` so I don't need to implement anything there, but I guess I could also write that out.

**Will this code continue to work in the future?**

It currently works in my setup, but I cannot test with every possible compiler and base package, especially future ones. What exactly is planned further down the road with `Monoid` escapes my grasp. Can you spot any problems with my approach?

Comment: I think the `semigroups` package automatically takes care of both cases. You can see this near the "`-- legacy configuration`" comment [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/semigroups-0.18.4/src/semigroups.cabal)